# borrar archivo csv mediante script

Tags: bash, csv

estoy haciendo diferentes transformaciones partiendo de un archivo CSV. [file1.csv]
Una vez hechas las transformaciones, las guardo en un nuevo archivo CSV. [file2.csv]
Quiero borrar el archivo de origen [file1.csv] una vez se ha creado el archivo nuevo [file2.csv]

La creación del nuevo archivo, mediante `bash` es sencilla: `>file2.csv`.
Lo que no sé es cómo hacer el borrado del CSV anterior.

Gracias.

Comment: Estás recibiendo el nombre de ambos ficheros como parámetros en un script?

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta aplicada ha sido:

```
rm `pwd`/file.csv
```

`` `pwd` `` recupera el directorio actual de uso.